# Cartoon with talking animals on a floating volcano powered island

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

The cartoon is about a group of talking animals that wash up on an island after a storm. It's a tropical island with a volcano and the animals aren't native to it, IIRC they were circus animals who's ship sank in the storm. By the end of the first episode the critters discover that the island floats  and that the volcano isn't a normal volcano: inside the caves there is a system that controls the lava. By "powering up" the volcano they can make the island move and I think there was a way to steer it too. Or maybe the island doesn't float and moves on the sea floor somehow, but it definitely is mobile. A polar bear is elected as the island's leader. This all happens in the first 1-2 episodes.

I watched this in the mid to late 90s so it's at least that old and it's definitely a series and not a one off movie. I'm nearly certain it's Western animation not anime. I think it might have been in French originally but it was dubbed. I lived in Europe when it was aired.

Comment: This show is really cool. I'll have to give you a -1 for lack of research, though. If you would have just googled literally the title of your question, you'd have found the answer on basically all of the first hits.

Comment: @Revetahw, not any more. Thanks to the power of Stack Exchange, this question is now the top hit in Google when searching for the wording of the title :) The wikipedia page is still the second hit though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I also remember watching this show in the 90's.

The cartoon is the European [*Noah's Island*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noah%27s_Island) where a group of talking animals discover a floating island that can be steered by directing lava through constructed channels.  The animals elect a polar bear leader "Noah" and use the island to travel the globe.

Answer (score 36):

#### [*Noah's Island*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noah%27s_Island) (1997 - 1999)

> The series focused on the adventures of a community of animals on a floating island that was originally part of the Canadian Coastline before being struck by a flaming meteorite. Their leader is a polar bear named Noah, and the community includes a pair of woolly mammoths called Salomi and Mammothsbody, as well as a group of animals from a closed down zoo who survived the sinking of a cargo ship. The Island is able to float because of a core of molten magma called the 'Fire-Bowl', which was formed from the meteorite. Noah uses the Fire-Bowl to steer the Island across the ocean, following a map that Salomi's father drew that leads to Diamantina, an uncharted island in the Indian Ocean where the animals can be safe from humans. During their quest, Noah and the community pass by several continents, rescuing animals in peril wherever they go.

This is the intro: